# If $ u \in W^{2,3} ( \Omega ) $ then $u \in L^3 ( \Omega )$?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

If $ u \in W^{2,3} ( \Omega ) $ then $u \in L^3 ( \Omega )$ ?

In [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space), the definition of Sobolev space is $$ W^{k,p} ( \Omega) = \{  u \in L^p ( \Omega)\mid D^{\alpha} u \in L^p , | \alpha| \leqslant k \},$$ where $ \Omega $ is  an open set in $\mathbb R^n$. So I think it's trivial, is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set-builder notation you see causes $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ to consist of functions in $L^p(\Omega)$.